# StreamingQueryException: Option 'basePath' must be a directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I wrote this code and I got this error: StreamingQueryException: Option 'basePath' must be a directory. My goal is to write the streams in file csv sink. The directories output_path/ and  checkpoint/ were created but are empty.

```
pipe = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
pipe_model = pipe.fit(dataset)
dataset= pipe_model.transform(dataset)
pipe_model.save("pipe_model")

df = spark\
.readStream\
.option("header", "true")\
.schema(schema)\
.csv("KDDTrain+.txt")

model = PipelineModel.load("pipe_model")
dataset= model.transform(df)

q=dataset.writeStream\
 .format("csv")\
 .option("header", "true")\
 .option("format", "append") \
 .queryName("okk")\
 .trigger(processingTime="10 seconds")\
 .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint/")\
 .option("path", "output_path/")\
 .outputMode("append") \
 .start()

q.awaitTermination()
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StreamingQueryException                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 q.awaitTermination()

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py:101, in StreamingQuery.awaitTermination(self, timeout)
    99     return self._jsq.awaitTermination(int(timeout * 1000))
    100 else:
--> 101     return self._jsq.awaitTermination()

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in 
JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py:117, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
   113 converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
   114 if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
   115     # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
   116     # JVM exception message.
--> 117     raise converted from None
   118 else:
   119     raise

StreamingQueryException: Option 'basePath' must be a directory === Streaming Query ===
Identifier: okk [id = a5a4ac3d-a533-409b-be0b-015ead8d2f4a, runId = 3e3b747d-ba4f 4948-bc9f-4ef360e08979]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {FileStreamSource[file:/home/jovyan/work/KDDTrain+.txt {"logOffset":0}} 

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE
```

where is the problem? and how to fix it please?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by reading from a directory not a file. i.e.:

```
df = spark\
  .readStream\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .schema(schema)\
  .csv("KDD/")
```

instead of:

```
 df = spark\
   .readStream\
   .option("header", "true")\
   .schema(schema)\
   .csv("KDDTrain+.txt")
```

Comment: A wildcard in the file path also works, e.g:
`.csv("KDDTrain*.txt")`